# Design a multi party Private Set Intersection protocol with unconditional zero-sharing

Tags: multiparty-computation, private-set-intersection

Unconditional zero-sharing was presented in the following paper

> [Practical Multi-party Private Set Intersection from Symmetric-Key Techniques](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/799),  by Vladimir Kolesnikov, Naor Matania, Benny Pinkas, Mike Rosulek, Ni Trieu

Unconditional zero-sharing allows all parties to obtain a share corresponding to each element in their set using the technique of zero-sharing.If they have a common element $x$,the sum of their corresponding shares equals $0$.
Based on the above facts,I wonder if it is correct to directly obtain the final intersection by using only zero-sharing technique?

Comment: If it was possible to easily get PSI from zero-sharing, without much extra effort, then I guess those authors would have done it?

Comment: Thanks for your response！I know that doing this should have issues, but I haven’t figured out what the problem is, or I’m not clear about the reason why the authors didn’t do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the paper [NTY21](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1221)? [NTY21] designed the zero-XOR protocol that includes zero-sharing and OPPRF. For $P_1$, OPPRF is used to get the other parties' share. If you don't use OPPRF to get the share, $P_1$ can't map the element $x$ to its corresponding share.

Comment: I think the key point is that using OPPRF/OKVS can bind the element and its corresponding share.